# Is there a signal processing or other python/R technique to split datasets at major points?

Tags: python, pandas, signal-processing

I have this [sample data](https://gist.github.com/pomkos/803acb3b7845b7cfe3031c722afbae2c) which recreates my problem:

[image]

I have roughly 40 or so datasets where we have an initial steady run, that suddenly bumps for 30 minutes and then suddenly bumps down. Previously I would just manually clip these, however I would like a more objective way to find the clip-points.

I've tried getting rolling means, diffs, sums and finding the clip points that way but it never seemed to work. I did get some promising results with `scipy.signal.find_peaks()`:

```py
def prominence_finder(my_series,threshold):
    '''
    Finds locations of major peaks of series
    '''
    from scipy.signal import find_peaks, peak_prominences
    peaks, _ = find_peaks(my_series,threshold=threshold)

    return peaks

test = pd.read_csv("sample_data(1).csv")
test_peaks = test['measure'][prominence_finder(test,threshold=0.02)].reset_index()
test_peaks.columns = ['index','peaks']
test = test.reset_index()

test2 = test.merge(test_peaks, on='index',how='left')

fix,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,6))
sns.scatterplot(x='time_series',y='measure',data=test2)
sns.scatterplot(x='time_series', y='peaks',data=test2, color='red',label='Calculated Peaks')
plt.title("Major Peaks")
plt.legend()
```

[image]

And by fiddling with the `threshold` or `distance` parameters of `find_peaks`, however that requires lots of manual input. Is there any way to automate cutting off the "warmup" and "cooldown" parts of this dataset?

Comment: Interesting, from the image I would expect that a rolling mean would show a big change (just hard to tell how large window would have to be)...

Answer (score 1):

One option may be to look for something that solves piecewise linear regression. Fortunately, there are a few technological solutions available. And especially since you're willing to also use R.

- [The R package MCP](https://github.com/lindeloev/mcp) is really impressive in how it identifies inflection points using a Bayesian approach.
- You should also take a look at sklearn's [DecisionTreeRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html)
- A third choice is a [GitHub gist by DataDog](https://github.com/DataDog/piecewise) with an [accompanying blog post](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/engineering/piecewise-regression/)

Option 2 is based on your inclusion of signal-processing as a tag. You might consider using a [Butterworth filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html).

A third option is to reconsider the statistical evaluation you've done. That's dependant on what the other datasets look like. Median is a much more robust metric of centrality that mean; dropping that by portion of a deviation is equally robust and might be suitable for your needs.

```
fix, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,6))
sns.scatterplot(x='time_series', y='measure', data=df, color='teal', label='Calculated Peaks')
plt.title("Major Peaks")

plt.axhline(df['measure'].mean(), color='blue')
plt.axhline(df['measure'].median(), color='black')
plt.axhline(df['measure'].median()-.25*df['measure'].std(),color='red', marker = '.', ls=':')

plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: While I will continue to try and get MCP to install on my instance, I did get some pretty impressive results with the DataDog library! It tends to favor shortening regression lines from the beginning than the end though. I will report back with MCP results.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for including a dataset. Incidentally, this is the short version of [another question asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62700172/optimization-on-piecewise-linear-regression/63007939#63007939). In that, I also mention using the derivative.

Comment: Also, there is [R2Py](https://rpy2.github.io/) if you using python now and don't really want to do it all over in R

Comment: Just wanted to update real quick. I decided to implement the DataDog ([option 3](https://gist.github.com/pomkos/1e3aeeaedfc4f47cd0cf070eccba5c5c)), mostly because I couldn't get option 1 installed and wasn't sure how to implement a DecisionTree with piecewise regression (newbie here). It works alright, however lots of manual input is needed. [Here is an example](https://imgur.com/a/IVscZq6). Do you happen to have any recommendations on how to automate using just coefficients (the only output from the library).

Comment: I updated the answer. I'd be interested in knowing if this helps.